# Can I run a Grunt task multiple times using a Grunt task while using different options/parameters?

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to create a grunt task which runs another grunt task using different parameters.

Let's assume I have the following grunt 'subtask':

`grunt.registerTask('subtask', ['js', 'css']);`

And some grunt configuration:

```
js: {
    src: [
         'code/<%= grunt.option("param1") %>/<%= grunt.option("param2") %>/js/<%= grunt.option("param2") %>.js'
          ],
    dest: 'temp/frontend.js'
},
```

I'd like to create a task which calls this subtask. The task should run the following commands:

```
subtask --param1=blue  --param2=red
subtask --param1=yellow  --param2=green
subtask --param1=blue  --param2=blue
subtask --param1=purple  --param2=green
```

To accomplish this I thought I'd create another task to run the above commands.

```
grunt.registerTask('triggerSubTask', function(arg0, arg1, arg2){

   if(arg1 === 'dark'){
     param1 = 'blue'
   } else if (arg1 === 'light'){
     param1 = 'yellow
   }
   //some more code

   if(arg2 === 'bright'){
     param1 = 'red'
   } else if (arg1 === 'light'){
     param1 = 'green'
   }

   //some more code in fact I am not using an if else here but some
     complexer code. param 1 and param 2 are different every time    
     grunt.task.run is called the following code will be a loop, but    
     I start hardcoded I want this task to do the following:


    grunt.config.set('param1', 'param1');
    grunt.config.set('param2', 'param2');

    var arg1 = 'dist';
    var arg2 = '--param1=' + arg1;
    var arg3 = '--param2=' + arg2;

    grunt.task.run(arg0);

    grunt.config.set('param1', 'param1');
    grunt.config.set('param2', 'param2');

    var arg1 = 'dist';
    var arg2 = '--param1=' + arg1;
    var arg3 = '--param2=' + arg2;

    grunt.task.run(arg0);
});
```

In my cmd I run the following command: `grunt bootstrap:subtask:dark:bright`

**The real problem:
I can't change the value of grunt.config('param1') while running grunt. Grunt doesn't allow me to do so.**

I hope that I have explained my problem correctly.